# Understanding Borel-Cantelli lemma in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Royden(4th ed) the lemma is stated as follows:

Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$a countable collection of measurable sets for which $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k)<\infty$. Then almost all $x$ in $X$ belong to at most a finite number of the $E_k$'s.

Now here what does it mean by "**almost all $x$ in $X$ belong to at most a finite number of the $E_k$'s."**

If I take $X=\mathbb{R}$, and $E_k$'s be any sets of measure $\frac{1}{k^2}$, then it satisfies the hypothesis of the lemma but almost all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ can not be in finite number of $E_k$'s.

Comment: Let $E_k=(k,k+1/k^2)$. Then each $x$ is in at most one $E_k$, so *a fortiori* almost all real $x$ are in a finite number of $E_k$s.

Comment: Expanding on Lord Shark's comment a little: ${\mathbb Q}$ is dense in ${\mathbb R}$ so it's easy to produce a countable collection of arbitrarily small sets for which any point of ${\mathbb R}$ is contained in only finitely many of them

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown means the $x$ which are in $\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$ ?

Comment: You can define the set $E = \cap_{k=1}^{\infty} \cup_{n=k}^{\infty} E_n$ as the set of all $x \in X$ such that $x$ is in an infinite number of the $E_i$ sets (this is also called $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} E_n$).  So then if the B-C assumption holds we conclude  $\mu(E)=0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown how all real $x$ can be in $E_k$, where $\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$ is a set of finite measure in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Perhaps your difficulty comes from forgetting that $0$ is finite. So any $x$ that is in none of the $E_k$'s is in "at most a finite number of the $E_k$'s."

Answer (score 1):

The statement in your question does not require $\{E_k\}$ are such that $X \subset \cup_1^\infty E_k$ and maybe could be better worded.

Say the $\{E_k\}$ are disjoint. Then $\sum_1^\infty 1_{E_k}(x)$ is the number of times $x$ is in $E_k$ for some k.

If $\sum_1^\infty \mu(E_k) < \infty$, the function $\sum_1^\infty 1_{E_k}(x)$ must be finite almost everywhere because it is integrable.

In other words, 'the set of points for which $x \in E_k$ for infinitely many k is measure zero.'